# How to set run as Android project by default in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, configuration

I'm developing an Android app under Eclipse v4.2 (Juno), and I want to set the preferences of my run button to always run my project as an Android app.

I just don't find the options to configure and set that!

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to run your app? Then it creates  an extra file with a .out extension?

Comment: nope, no file with .out extension!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

Right-click your project → *Run application as...* → there under section *Android*, choose *"Browse..."* and select your project.

Then apply/run, and it should be saved for you.

You can also choose on these options if you want to select an AVM / device or if Eclipse should use the best device for you.

Comment: what I get is: right-click your project >> run as: 1 Android application, 2 JUnit test, 3 Java Applet and so on... but what i dont what to do is allways make the same process, I mean, I want : click run and by default allways run as Android app

Comment: just click the play button and it should default to that

Comment: just as TMP said, it should be default after first run.maybe a .project file is missing?